# Unable to use Yfinance library with multiple errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, yfinance

Was able to use last night, and copy and pasted ranaroussi his source code on pypi.org for yfinance and methods are no longer working today. Is there an issue with the API or is there something I need to update in the code?

```
import yfinance as yf

msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")

# get stock info
msft.info

# get historical market data
hist = msft.history(period="max")

# show meta information about the history (requires history() to be called first)
msft.history_metadata

# show actions (dividends, splits, capital gains)
msft.actions

# show dividends
msft.dividends

# show splits
msft.splits


# show capital gains (for mutual funds & etfs)
msft.capital_gains

# show share count
msft.shares

# show financials:
# - income statement
msft.income_stmt
msft.quarterly_income_stmt
# - balance sheet
msft.balance_sheet
msft.quarterly_balance_sheet
# - cash flow statement
msft.cashflow
msft.quarterly_cashflow
# see `Ticker.get_income_stmt()` for more options

# show major holders
msft.major_holders

# show institutional holders
msft.institutional_holders

# show mutualfund holders
msft.mutualfund_holders

# show earnings
msft.earnings
msft.quarterly_earnings

# show sustainability
msft.sustainability

# show analysts recommendations
msft.recommendations
msft.recommendations_summary
# show analysts other work
msft.analyst_price_target
msft.revenue_forecasts
msft.earnings_forecasts
msft.earnings_trend

# show next event (earnings, etc)
msft.calendar

# Show future and historic earnings dates, returns at most next 4 quarters and last 8 quarters by default. 
# Note: If more are needed use msft.get_earnings_dates(limit=XX) with increased limit argument.
msft.earnings_dates

# show ISIN code - *experimental*
# ISIN = International Securities Identification Number
msft.isin

# show options expirations
msft.options

# show news
msft.news

# get option chain for specific expiration
opt = msft.option_chain('YYYY-MM-DD')
# data available via: opt.calls, opt.puts
```

Getting the error "self._scrape(self.proxy)" as well as
"quote_summary_store = json_data['QuoteSummaryStore']
TypeError: string indices must be integers"

If anyone knows why this may not be working that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], read: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic] and how to create a [mre]. Please provide the complete traceback and distill this code down to the bare minimum required to reproduce the error.

Comment: @MichaelRuth that is my issue, i do not know where the error is coming from.

Comment: Me neither, please provide the complete traceback and I can help you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue since Saturday, and yfinance==0.2.4 does fix the issue.  For some reason my IDE was using a difference instance which was pointing to 0.2.3.  Check the version being used with yf.**version**